# Nvidia drivers bombing out

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I installed, and selected the drivers and it was all sweet for a few days. now i've updated my kernel and the nvidia drivers simply won't load. I've tried doing a apt purge nvidia* and reinstalling. I've tried booting to an older kernel. I've tried swapping between the open source graphics driver and the nvidia one. nothing works.

> System:   Host: Lola Kernel: 5.4.0-37-generic x86_64 bits: 64
> Desktop: Cinnamon 4.4.8 Distro: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia  Machine:
> Type: Desktop Mobo: ASRock model: X299 Taichi serial: 
> UEFI [Legacy]: American Megatrends v: P1.20 date: 06/26/2017  CPU:
> 14-Core: Intel Core i9-9940X type: MT MCP speed: 1200 MHz    min/max:
> 1200/4500 MHz  Graphics:   Device-1: NVIDIA driver: N/A    Display:
> x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: nouveau,vesa    unloaded: modesetting
> resolution: 1280x1024~76Hz    OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0 256
> bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8  Network:   Device-1: Intel Ethernet I219-V
> driver: e1000e    Device-2: Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone
> Peak] driver: iwlwifi    Device-3: Intel I211 Gigabit Network driver:
> igb  Drives:   Local Storage: total: 6.37 TiB used: 1.63 TiB (25.6%)
> Info:   Processes: 447 Uptime: 1m Memory: 62.52 GiB used: 914.5 MiB
> (1.4%)    Shell: bash inxi: 3.0.32  theironknuckle@Lola:~$

Comment: If you install a new kernel, then you'll want to re-install the nvidia driver so that it'll build against the new kernel.

Comment: @AndyDalton as mentioned, I have already tried "apt purge nvidia*" and reinstalling. didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

do you still have the old kernel ?
if you still have it just choose Advanced options in the grub menu you'll see the old kernel and just boot into it

Comment: this doesn't help at all. regardless of what kernel i use, everything is broken

Comment: do tested nouveau driver ?? (ts open source driver of nvidia )